# Calculate time difference between 2 dates and give outputs in total hours is generating output as #### which is wrong

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to Excel, VBA, Macro. My macro was working fine because I gave a simple formula, for example, D2(column name)-C2(column name) = Total time in HH:MM format new column. But I notice for some output is just #### not sure what is wrong.  1).Column)).Formula = _
"=" & cl.Offset(1, 0).Address(0, 0) & "-" & .Cells(2, col1).Address(0, 0)

```
            cl.Offset(, 1).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "[hh]:mm"
```

Comment: did you try making the column wider?

Comment: Yes I made the column wider it gives output as ####

Comment: Then it is negative and one cannot have a negative time.

Comment: If you don't know which of your columns contains the bigger value and you are just interested in the absolute time difference between both dates use the `ABS` function like `=ABS(C:C-B:B)`. This way it doesn't matter because the outcome is always positive.

Comment: not sure how do I do that in the codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue occurs because your date in J is earier than in I and therefore the result is negative. You can use the `ABS()` function to get the absolute difference as positive value.

Therefore adjust your formula as below:

```
.Formula = "=ABS(" & cl.Offset(1, 0).Address(0, 0) & "-" & .Cells(2, col1).Address(0, 0) & ")"
```

Comment: @PEH thanks this was super perfect :) Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

You have an incorrect formula in this line:

```
.Range(cl.Offset(1, 1), .Cells(lastR, cl.Offset(1, 1).Column)).Formula = _
"=" & cl.Offset(1, 0).Address(0, 0) & "-" & .Cells(**2**, col1).Address(0, 0)
```

Why `.Cells(2, col1)`?  This is always giving you row2 of column 1.

Also, after this line:

```
If cl.Value = "Full Out Gate at Inland or Interim Point (Destination)_recvd"
```

Then
Add:

```
If cl.Offset(0,1).Value = "Response Time" Then Exit For
```

This will keep you from inserting a new column every time you run the macro.

Try using clear variable names and consistent method for referring to rows and columns.

```
actCol = col1
recvdCol = cl.Column
responseCol = cl.offset(0,1).Column
.Range(lastR, responseCol).Formula = _
"= Abs(" & .Cells(lastR, recvdCol) & "-" & .Cells(lastR, actCol).Address(0, 0) & ")"
```

I would use a simpler approach.  Highlight the entire table, and click "Format as Table", and be sure to check off "My table has headers."  This will give you a named range (default name is Table1, but you can change it).  Then, in the Response Time column, simply enter your formula on the first row of the table, but use your mouse to select the cells instead of typing in a cell name like "I2".  You will find that the resulting formula includes something like `=[@actl]-[@recvd]`, except that the actl and recvd will be replaced by your actual column names.  And, the formula will apply to every row of the table.  If you add a new row, the formula will automatically appear in that row.  No code needed.

If you have a reason to use code instead of a Table (named ranges), then I would recommend (1) this code be placed directly in the "Main" worksheet module and (2) use use the "Worksheet_Changed" procedure. [Microsoft Excel VBA Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.Change).  In this case, any time the

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Note, Target is the Range of the cell(s) that just changed.
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Target.Column) = "Full Out Gate at Inland or Interim Point (Destination)_actual" Then
        ' Cell in actual column was modified.  Let's set the formula in the Response Time column:
        On Error Goto EH
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ' Add your code here.  You'll need to modify it somewhat to accommodate this methodology.
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
EH:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Err.Raise  ' expand this to whatever error you wish to raise
End Sub
```

[Err.Raise help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/raise-method)